# Should we sort country list?

Tags: html, usability

I just wrote a list of country from the [Wikipedia ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1)

My goal is to use it in select inside my xhtml, but it's a huge list. How many are you from Aruba? But how many are you from United Kingdom, France, or even United States of America?

Sometimes, I can see that the most common countries are listed at the top of the list.

Is it a good practice? Why and why not?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a web application. I'm not sure if any sites do it, but you could sort the list alphabetically, and use IP Geolocation to guess a country to put as the default. It won't be right 100% of the time, but it might make filling out the form easier for the people you do get right...

Comment: There's the solution I was alluding to.

Comment: Agreed, this is the most user-friendly approach, and for cases where it isn't detected right, a plain alphabetic sorting should be sufficient.

Comment: I got the bar for your post as soon as I clicked to post my answer. I think it has some drawbacks, like people who use proxies in other countries, but I think sorting alphabetically (something expected) plus a good guess will help most of your audience.

Answer (score 17):

I've seen this done where the top 3-5 countries (by volume) are duplicated at the top of the list... then a break is displayed and ***all*** countries are then listed in alphabetical order.  This obviously only helps a certain set of your users but if you know that 90% of them come from within the top (3-5) countries... this might be helpful.

e.g.

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Quick Picks">
    <option>Australia</option>
    <option>Canada</option>
    <option>Germany</option>
    <option>United Kingdom</option>
    <option>United States</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="All Countries">
    <option>A....</option>
    <option>A....</option>
    <option>A....</option>
    <option>B....</option>
    <option>B....</option>
    <option>C....</option>
    <option>C....</option>
    ...
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

e.g. *removed dead ImageShack link*

*Note:* "by volume" I mean by volume of traffic to your particular site/application.

Comment: +1, this is the way I always handle it. However I don't just display the remaining countries, I display them all regardless of whether they were included at the top. That way if someone does manage to skip over the top, they don't scroll through the list wondering "Where the hell is Canada?".

Comment: guess my wording wasn't quite clear... yes, the top ones are duplicates... then all countries are listed below (even if in the top set)

Comment: You still break search-as-you-type that way. If list was properly sorted alphabetically, I'd expect "Un" to find "United Arab Emirates", not "United Kingdom" as it will in your case. The bigger problem is that if every site varies its list, it becomes impossible to use the same search sequences everywhere.

Comment: @Pavel - true... I guess its a matter of tradeoffs... I've yet to find the perfect solution.

Answer (score 7):

Think of your common web user... It's easier for someone (who doesn't know they can just type the first letter of their country and find it fast that way) to find his country in an alphabetically sorted list then a list sorted arbitrarily based on web population.

I recommend sticking to alphabetical sorting.

Comment: It's not me, but I would assume that they believe it is harder for someone to find his country in an alphabetically sorted list.

Answer (score 2):

List them alphabetically, and duplicate your primary markets at the top.

Don't just move them to the top - I've wasted too much time looking for the United Kingdom under "U" in drop down menus for that.

Answer (score 1):

Why: For the exact reason you mentioned; if you expect most/all of your users to be one country, listing it first will help the user experience.

Why not: Every one not in the most populous countries may wonder why those countries were listed first (almost like a form of privilege).  But if you don't want to worry about that you do not have to.  Plus, users can still start typing their country in, and locate it that way, so this may not be a big deal.

There may also be solutions to figure out where the user is sitting, but I'm not sure about that.  If there are, that may be the best of all worlds.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is to stick to alphabetic order; I believe almost everyone starts typing the first letters of their country as they open the drop down. :-)

Comment: Power users do, anyway. I tried to get my parents to do that, and they don't.

Comment: Your, thomas, only power users, however alphabetic is still a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your target audience, it can be either convenient or offensive. I know that I personally find the practice mildly insulting. In addition, it somewhat breaks the ability to quickly select items by typing the first few letters - when everyone sorts it the same way, when you type the same thing, you get the same result. But if you put some countries on the top (and different people do it for different countries), then results may be different.

Answer (score 1):

List them alphabetically. Even us Americans ought to understand that.

However, I do recommend you consider something a bit fancier, like a text box with an auto-suggest list. You could add a dropdown arrow at the side for those who like to scan through lists, though I suspect that many of them will use the keyboard to at least get to the vicinity of the country they're looking for).

OBTW, I presume you got the English-language list of countries?

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree that alphabelically is the most universally understood mechanism. Custom sorting will most likely cause some users confusion.

Will the application be localized in other languages?  Make sure to take into account that the list should be alphabetically sorted based on the users languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the full list in alphabetical order and set the country that you expect more users to be from as the option selected by default.